# Problem on concept of exact differention equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve an ODE as follows
$$M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = 0,$$
where
$$ M:= \frac{\partial R}{\partial x}+ \lambda(x,y), $$
$$N:=\frac{\partial R}{\partial y}, $$
and $R$, $\lambda$ are differentiable functions of $(x,y) $. How can i solve this equation?

My attemption:
We have
$$dR +\lambda dx =0.$$
By taking the total derivation one gets
$$d\lambda \wedge dx =0.$$
Then
$$\Big(\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y} dy \Big) \wedge dx =0 $$
therefore
$$\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y} dy\wedge dx =0 $$
and then we conclude
$$\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y} =0 $$
But this conclusion is the exactness condition and the equation is not exact. I do not know how can one solve this equation.
Thanks for any help